# How Can I configure the SharePoint diagnostic logging to log detailed error when using visual studio to deploy solution?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How Can I configure the SharePoint diagnostic logging to log detailed error when using visual studio to deploy solution?I am using visual studio to deploy solution in a dev enviroment.However, when I got and error shown in visual studio like add solution failed ....,nothing is logged in SharePoint log,how can I configure the SharePoint 2010 diagnostic logging to log detailed error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Central administration go to monitoring and then diagnostic logging and then Under SharePoint Foundation --> 1) Feature Infrastructure AND 2) Topology

For both line items, select EventLevel = Verbose, TraceLevel = Verbose

Then look for the events in SharePoint ULS logs.

Comment: I still like to set the verbosity level of the msbuild inside Visual Studio 2010 to normal or detailed (dont go further otherwise it's way too much).  Combination of that and the ULS (verbose,verbose) can give you a complete picture.  Sometime, I wish i can turn up the logging inside the SharePoint plugin to VS but have yet to find a way for that.